# Changing system font in macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, catalina, font

I am using macOS Catalina, and I would like to change the system font to something other than San Francisco.

I tried [TinkerTool](https://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html), but it doesn’t really work.

Comment: MacOS does not really lend itself to customizations of this kind. The system is now completely 'sealed off' from modification. While it is possible to boot to Recovery or another volume, disable SIP, and perform the necessary alteration, you will have to do this every time there's a system update (so, every 2 months on average).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our only hope is that the gentleman who makes this tool figures out a way to make it work. I have been using this tool for years and has made my experience much nicer as I am not a fan of the San Francisco font. There was a few promising details in the issue tracker but as of yet no workaround.

https://github.com/jenskutilek/FiraSystemFontReplacement